# Golang postgres Commit unknown command error?

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

Using `postgres 9.3`, `go 1.6`

I've been trying to use transactions with the `go` `pq` library.

```
// Good
txn, _ := db.Begin()
txn.Query("UPDATE t_name SET a = 1")
err := txn.Commit() // err is nil

// Bad
txn, _ := db.Begin()
txn.Query("UPDATE t_name SET a = $1", 1)
err := txn.Commit() // Gives me a "unexpected command tag Q" error
// although the data is committed
```

For some reason, when I execute a `Query` with parameters, I always get an `unexpected command tag Q` error from the `Commit()`.  What is this error (what is Q?) and why am I getting it?

I believe [this](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/fde2b33cb1c820fbd3ff19eb9414be2d86b1bd12/conn.go#L557) is where the error is created.

Comment: Your statement does not return any rows. Try Exec. Q is the protocol  identifier sent to the backend for a query, for an execute it sends E.

Comment: You're ignoring the error returns from `db.Begin()` and `txn.Query()`; possibly one of those has an error that may shed some light on the issue before the `txn.Commit()`

Comment: @DmitriGoldring, Thanks! That solved it.

Answer (score 10):

To start of i agree whit Dmitri from the comments, in this case you should probably use Exec.

However after receiving this same issue I started digging:

[Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx.Query) returns 2 arguments a Rows pointer and an error. What you always have to do with a Rows object is to close it when you are don with it:

```
// Fixed
txn, _ := db.Begin()
rows, _ := txn.Query("UPDATE t_name SET a = $1", 1)
//Read out rows
rows.Close() //<- This will solve the error
err := txn.Commit()
```

I was however unable to see any difference in the traffic to the database when using `rows.Close()` witch indicates to me that this might be a bug in `pq`.